# DAAB 5.0 with LINQ-to-SQL mimicry

Tags: linq, enterprise-library, stored-procedures

I was looking at the EntLib 5.0 video on their website and I saw a preview that uses like a different IDataReader to fill-in objects to work like a LINQ-to-Objects shortcut (instead of a LINQ-to-SQL). I think it uses sprocs class, but I couldn't find it on the library.

Any idea where I can read more about it? Google isn't cooperating very well.